# R not displaying my ordered factor in order?

Tags: r, categories, orders, factors

[Picture of Resulted Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWGs1.png)I am trying to make a code for taking a table of concentration data for PM2.5, calculate the AQI, put it in a table, and then plot the results.

No matter what I do, even making the AQI_category as an ordered factor, it keeps displaying "Unhealthy" before "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups" even though "UFSG" should come before "Unhealthy" on the AQI scale.

Here is the code:

```
#concentration data in ug/m3
pm2.5_ugm3<- c(10.6,12.7,35.1, 2.5, 35.5,14.9, 20.2,1.3,6 ,17.4 ,40.1,60,19,5.5,3.8,10,9.9 ,4.3,36,15 ,3,7.2,16.4,26.5,1,2.5,18.8,19.2,14,3,12)

#calculate AQIs  
result = ifelse((pm2.5_ugm3>=0 & pm2.5_ugm3<=12), 50/12*(pm2.5_ugm3-0)+0, 
                ifelse((pm2.5_ugm3>=12.1 & pm2.5_ugm3<=35.4),(100-51)/(35.4-12.1)*(pm2.5_ugm3-12.1)+51, 
                       ifelse((pm2.5_ugm3>=35.5 & pm2.5_ugm3<=55.4), (150-101)/(55.4-35.5)*(pm2.5_ugm3-35.5)+101, 
                              ifelse((pm2.5_ugm3>=55.5 & pm2.5_ugm3<=150.4), (200-151)/(150.4-55.5)*(pm2.5_ugm3-55.5)+151,"NA" ))))

#create AQI object that rounds result to 0 digits
AQI <- round(as.numeric(result), digits = 0)

#calculate AQI result meaning
AQI_Category <- (ifelse((AQI>=0 & AQI<=50), "Good", 
                                 ifelse((AQI>=51 & AQI<=100),"Moderate", 
                                        ifelse((AQI>=101 & AQI<=150), "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups", 
                                               ifelse((AQI>=151 & AQI<=200), "Unhealthy","NA" )))))
str(AQI_Category)


#make a table
AQI_Table <- data.frame(pm2.5_ugm3,AQI,AQI_Category)

#orders AQI category by magnitude
AQI_Table$AQI_Category <- as.factor(ordered(AQI_Table$AQI_Category, levels =c('Good','Moderate','Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups','Unhealthy')))
str(AQI_Table)



#stripchart & boxplot

stripchart(AQI ~ AQI_Category, vertical= TRUE, method = "jitter",
           pch = 16,
           col = c('forestgreen','goldenrod','orange1','firebrick'),
           main = "January 2024 AQI")
```

and I always get the attached chart. any ideas? Thanks in Advance!

additionally this code keeps ordering the levels wrong:

```
AQI_Category <- as.factor(ordered(ifelse((AQI>=0 & AQI<=50), "Good", 
                       ifelse((AQI>=51 & AQI<=100),"Moderate", 
                              ifelse((AQI>=101 & AQI<=150), "Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups", 
                                     ifelse((AQI>=151 & AQI<=200), "Unhealthy","NA" ))))))
```

it gives:
"Levels: Good Moderate Unhealthy Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups"

So it seems my ordered factor is ordering wrong and I don't know why?

tried making AQI category as an ordered factor, expected it to put them in the right order, it keeps putting UFSG before Unhealthy

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO. I can not reproduce your problem, because you did not provide a minimal reproducible example - which is standard practice here. 
However, I know your problem from experience and very likely UFSG contains `NA`s. ggplot ist putting categories that have `NA`s first.

Comment: Hi - thanks, I'm new. I'm not using ggplot for the stripchart, just base R. how can i attached the sample data set I used so someone can re-produce? or should I provide the code with just a list of concentrations? thanks!

Comment: I updated the post to have the data as a vector so it can be reproduced! many thanks!

Comment: Here is how to write a good minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. basically, try to find either an example data set, in R, which represents your own data, such as `iris` or `Trees` or `mtcars`, or alternatively, create a dataset from scratch that contains a minimal amount of variables and rows. If this seems like too much work, you can post the output of `dput(your_dataset)`. - This allows people to copy the code and have your data on their machine without downloading and reading csv files. 
Next step: keep it minimal, that means pin down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you accidentally used the vectors `AQI` and `AQI_Category` instead of the data frame columns `AQI_Table$AQI` and `AQI_Table$AQI_Category`. This can be fixed with one line of code, adding the `data` argument to the plot.

```r
stripchart(AQI ~ AQI_Category, vertical= TRUE, method = "jitter",
           pch = 16,
           col = c('forestgreen','goldenrod','orange1','firebrick'),
           main = "January 2024 AQI",
           data = AQI_Table)
```

[image: output]

This can be prevented by thinking about good variable names. Something like `aqi$category` would be a better name for `AQI_Table$AQI_Category`.